# Breadcrumb using Backbone Marionette module

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to implement breadcrumb using Backbone with Marionette's Module.

My idea is, to the UL tag add the LI tag one by one.

In my HTML I have a UL tag with id 'Breadcrumb'.

I created breadcrumb Module as below:

```
App.module("BreadcrumbModule", function(BreadcrumbModule){

var Breadcrumb = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name        : '',
        link        : ''
    } 
});

var BreadcrumbList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Breadcrumb
});

var BreadcrumbView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    render : function() {
        $(this.el).html('<a href="#' + this.model.get('link') + '" class="tabSection">' + this.model.get('name') + '</a>');
        return this;
    }
});

var BreadcrumbListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '#Breadcrumb',

    initialize : function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'appendBreadcrumb');
        this.collection = new BreadcrumbList();
        this.collection.bind('add', this.appendBreadcrumb);
    },

    render:function(){ 
        $.each(this.collection.models, function(i, breadcrumb){
            self.appendBreadcrumb(breadcrumb);
        });
    },

    appendBreadcrumb: function(breadcrumb) {
        var breadcrumbView = new BreadcrumbView({
            model : breadcrumb
        });

        // THIS IS NOT WORKING!
        $(this.el).append(breadcrumbView.render().el);
    }
});

// Public function    
BreadcrumbModule.getBreadcrumbListView = function(){
    return new BreadcrumbListView();
}

BreadcrumbModule.getBreadcrumb = function(breadcrumb){
    return new Breadcrumb(breadcrumb);
}
});
```

Tried to access in the same module:

```
breadcrumbListView = new BreadcrumbListView();
breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb({name : 'Home',link : 'home'});
breadcrumbView = new BreadcrumbView({model:breadcrumb});    
breadcrumbListView.collection.add(breadcrumb);
```

In another module I'm adding an item to the breadcurmb as follows:

```
this.breadcrumbListView = App.BreadcrumbModule.getBreadcrumbListView();
breadcrumb = App.BreadcrumbModule.getBreadcrumb({link: 'home', name: 'Home'});
this.breadcrumbListView.collection.add(breadcrumb);
```

In both of the cases it is not working. I checked the LI tag is generated properly.
But it is not adding the value to the BreadcrumbListView's  el '#Breadcrumb'.

in the function appendBreadcrumb() if I give as follows also its not working, but from the firebug it is working.

```
 $('#Breadcrumb').html('ADD SOME TEXT');
```

But my main container $('#contentContainer') have scope and we can set value to it.

contentContainer  -> in the HTML.

Breadcrumb        -> in the template file.

That means from the view I cannot set value to an id coming from a template file.

Note: I'm not using RequireJS.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

//San.

Comment: might be the same issue as you were having before, when is #Breadcrumb added to the page? as I have your code working (outside of marionette but the core of the code) in this code pen when #Breadcrumb is part of the html at load.http://codepen.io/leighquince/pen/hmced

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My code structure is, in a module there is a view and a controller. In the view, _.template() I'm loading the HTML template in which the '#Breadcrumb' is available. In the controller's initialize() after creating the object of the view I'm accessing the breadcrumb. When we create a views' object it do not set its template?

Comment: Template is loaded with this fuction: function getTemplate(url) {
    var data = "<h1> failed to load url : " + url + "</h1>";
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        contentType: 'text/html',
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
            data = response;
        }
    });
    return data;    
}

Comment: In my view DIV id can be accessible if it is in the HTML and DIV id is not accessible if it is from template file. What should I do to get access of the DIV id in the view, if the DIV id is loaded from a template?

Comment: As you are using `Marionette` already, you should definitely refactor your code to use its `ItemView` and `CollectionView` features as this will make half of your code redundant: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v1.8.5/marionette.collectionview.html

Comment: I'm new to Backbone and Marionette. I just modified(in my local) the code with ItemView and CollectionView, but its not working. In the example link there is no CollectionView used. What I want to implement is, when I add a new breadcrumb item (LI) to the collection it should add to the UL. Could you please modify the sample code according to it?